# Will she be able to fit in the Philippine Airline Boeing 777-300er seat comfortably?

Tags: air-travel, safety, aircraft, boeing, philippine-airlines

So I am going on a trip with my family to the Philippines. The only concern before buying our tickets is our rather large cousin. She stands at 5'6'' and is about 280lbs. She wears as size 24-26 pants. Does anyone know if she will fit the seats okay? I mean if she has to squeeze into the seat until after they are in the air and seat belt lights are off, that't okay. Im rather skinny and could leave my air rest up to give her some extra room. I just dont want to get onto the plane and have her be embarrassed later on.

Comment: You may find http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3357/101 interesting - it's not quite the same, but may give you some ideas.

Comment: 24-26 on what clothing scale?

Comment: If she fits into other airlines' typical seats, she should be fine on a Philippine Airlines B777. Also, most Filipinos being fairly small, the chance of 2 (or 3!) large people being seated side-by-side is much lower than on U.S. airlines.

Answer (score 8):

The Philippine Airlines 777-300ER has some of the better seats in Economy of any airline.

Excluding bulk-head/exit row, the economy seats have a pitch of between 33-34", a width of 18.5", and a 6 degree recline in a 3-4-3 configuration.  Whilst that's hardly luxurious, it's at least as good as the majority of airlines, and better than most!

As with many wide-body planes, the cabin tapers off towards the end of the cabin, and the seat layout becomes 2-4-2.  Many people find that the 2-seat areas give extra room, especially in the "window" seat where there is normally a gap between the edge of the seat and the actual wall/window.  If you can't get one of these seats I'd suggest an aisle seat as they aren't as restrictive as the window/middle seats.

Exit rows and Bulk-head rows will give more legroom, but normally have narrower seats due to the tray-table being in the armrest rather than on the seat in-front.

Unfortunately I can't directly answer your question without knowing exactly how large your cousin is, but I can say that if she is able to fit in any Economy class seat on any airline, she should be fine on the Philippine 777-300.

Comment: Unfortunately on the 777 (and almost all other airlines from memory) the armrest on the window seat does not raise. Rest of info gets a +1 from me. The bulkhead seats are narrower due to the tray table in the armrest, the exit rows (over wing) do not have this issue. Also note that the window seat usually has limited legroom on some airliners as this is where the backseat entertainment control module is located.

Answer (score 5):

[Seatplans.com](http://www.seatplans.com) has an extensive [review](http://www.seatplans.com/tried-and-tested/airlines/philippine-airlines/philippine-airlines-b777-300er-fiesta-class) of Philippine Airline's 777-300ER "Fiesta" Class. They also have the full [seat map](http://www.seatplans.com/airlines/Philippine-Airlines/seatplans/B777-300ER-1).

Unfortunately, the other seat recommendation sites below currently do not have Philippine's 777s, but they may add it in the near future...

- [SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com)
- [SeatExpert](http://www.seatexpert.com)
- [SeatMaestro](http://www.seatmaestro.com)
- [SkyTrax](http://www.airlinequality.com/Experience/seat_plans.htm)

Comment: Just as an update, SeatGuru has it now.